# In JavaScript what is the meaning of (factory).factory.selector = originalSelector?

Tags: javascript, angular, syntax

I came upon this page where (in german) is explained how to start multiple Angular instances on a page. Towards the end, I find this line:

```
(factory).factory.selector = originalSelector;
```

What does the `(factory).factory` syntax mean? Its from here:
[Link to code.](https://www.bluesky-it.ch/blog/71917ECE-131E-4FA0-A499-5E5C353F6B42/Mehrere-Instanzen-einer-Angular4-Applikation-auf-einer-HTML-Seite)

Is this an immediately invoked function to `ngDoBootstrap` where the `factory` parameter is provided as an argument and on the return value `factory` property is called using `.`-dot syntax?

Comment: Unnecessarily confusing way of writing `factory.factory.selector = originalSelector`

Comment: `(factory)` just evaluates to `factory`.  I dunno why they wrapped it in parenthesis like that.

Comment: Ok, wired. I didn't understand either. Also bit higher there is another piece of syntax I havent seen before: `ngDoBootstrap(appRef: ApplicationRef)` Is this vanilla JavaScript? What does the `:` mean here and is there a reference for this kind of declaration on MDN? Don't know under what search term to look for...

Comment: Not vanilla JavaScript – it’s TypeScript.